# Regex to split a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string input like:

```
var input = "1. J. Carter 2. Mark R. 1000. Axl"
```

There can be any number of names, but the point is that I need to split this string in an array like this

- J. Carter
- Mark R.
- Axl

I think there should be a way to do this with regex, but I'm completely new in this theme, so I would really appreciate your help.

thanks

Comment: There isnt enough information here for us to help. Are all the "names" after a number followed by a period?

Comment: At you saying that the pattern is: "[number][dot][whitespace][stuff to find][whitespace]?  If so, point it out.  Also, if that's the pattern, it's pretty easy to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following regex

```
\d+\.\s(?<name>[^\d]+)?\s?
```

Which can be broken down as

- Any numberic digit, 1 or more reps
- A literal `.`
- A single whitespace
- A named capture group named `name`, containing:

  - Any character which is not a digit, one or more reps
- Zero or one whitespace character

You can then retrieve the name portion using `match.Groups["name"].Value`

```
var input = "1. J. Carter 2. Mark R. 1000. Axl";
var regex = new Regex(@"\d+\.\s(?<name>[^\d]+)?\s?");

var matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach(Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["name"].Value);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/TWS82231

Answer (score 0):

With the input :

```
var input = "1. J. Carter 2. Mark R. 1000. Axl"
```

and this regex :

```
    string strRegex = @"(\d)+.";
    Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
    string strTargetString = @"1. J. Carter 2. Mark R. 1000. Axl""";
    string strReplace = @";";

    return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

it will give you the output:

```
; J. Carter ; Mark R. ; Axl"
```

Next, you split output by `;` to get the array of names

Comment: yes that was it, it works just as expected, thank you very much

Comment: @JKarov If the provided answer helped you, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @JKarov finally, you resolve your problem?. Don't forget to mark the answer if my answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this with regex. This should work for you:

```
var names = new Regex(@"\d+\.\s+([^\d]+)").Matches(input)
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
                .ToList();
```

- The `\d+` matches one or more digits.
- The `\.` matches a literal `.` character.
- The `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters.
- The `()` creates a capture group.
- The `[^\d]+` matches one or more non-digits (basically the name).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as a regex:

```
((?<Number>\d+)\.\s+)(?<Name>[a-zA-Z\.\s]+)(\s*)
```

For every match, you get a group named "Number" that contains one or more digits (the `\d+`) and a group named "Name" that has the name you are looking for.  The `[a-zA-Z\.\s]+` associated with Name says any number of upper or lower case letters, dots or whitespace.  The `\.\s+` says "a dot followed by one or more white space characters, while the trailing `(\s*)` swallows any possible trailing space.

Parsing your string, I get three matches, with the numbers and names as you'd expect.